# NetSuite: SuiteSQL - linking customer deposit, deposit application and invoice

Tags: netsuite-rest-api

A customer deposit record in NetSuite application shows the Applied To tab which lists the invoice that it is applied to via a deposit application. How one connect the three records together using SuiteSQL. I.e. what "tables" does one join on what fields.

Deposit Application record has "createdfrom" field in transactionline which points to Customer Deposit.
Not sure how to get to the invoice record to which the customer deposit was applied to.

Many thanks in advance